# Access subqueries - values not referenced

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, median

I have two tables:
TblA TargetDate and TblB DepartmentName

The two tables are joined using a composite key which consists of four fields: 
RecNr, DiarieNr, ReportMonth, ReportYear

```
TblA
RecNr,  DiarieNr, ReportMonth, ReportYear, TargetDate,  DepartmentName
1       1000      7            2013        01/08/2013   DeptA
2       1000      7            2013        01/10/2013   DeptA
3       1000      7            2013        01/08/2013   DeptC
1       3000      7            2013        01/07/2013   DeptB
2       3000      7            2013        01/09/2013   DeptB
3       3000      7            2013        01/01/2014   DeptA

TblB
RecNr,  DiarieNr, ReportMonth, ReportYear, Completed
1       1000      7            2013        2013
2       1000      7            2013        2013
3       1000      7            2013        2013
1       3000      7            2013        2013
2       3000      7            2013        2012
3       3000      7            2013        2013
```

Now - I need to create a summary of the Median for each Department for entries that were completed in 2013, like this:

```
Department Name     TargetDate
DeptA               01/10/2013
DeptB               01/07/2013
DeptC               01/08/2013
```

My best and only guess to do this is like the query below, but when I run the sql in  Access I'm prompted to provide a DepartmentName. So I guess that it's not referenced properly from the main query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.DepartmentName,
(SELECT TOP 1 TargetDate 
  FROM (
       SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT TargetDate 
         FROM TblA A1  
        WHERE DepartmentName=A2.DepartmentName 
        ORDER BY A1.DepartmentName
   ) AS A2 
  WHERE A.DepartmentName=A2.DepartmentName 
  ORDER BY TargetDate
 )
FROM TblB M 
INNER JOIN TblA A ON M.ReportMonth=A.ReportMonth 
    AND M.ReportYear=A.ReportYear 
    AND M.DiarieNr=A.DiarieNr 
    AND M.RecNr=A.RecNr
WHERE A.DepartmentName<>'' AND YEAR(TblB.Completed)=2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use the `alias` of a table, the correct syntax is:
    FROM TblB As M

You missed out the `AS`

You would be better off using the Ms Access query designer which would automatically generate the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `AS` can be omitted in the SQL standard. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL))

Comment: You are right! The queries above have been slightly modified for the sake of simplification.